# Download million files from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have million of files in different folders on S3 bucket.

The files are very small. I wish to download all the files that are 
under folder named `VER1`. The folder `VER1` contains many subfolders,
I wish to download all the million files under all the subfolders of `VER1`.

(e.g `VER1`-> `sub1`-> `file1.txt` ,`VER1`-> `sub1` -> `subsub1` -> `file2.text`, etc.)

What is the fastest way to download all the files?

Using `s3 cp`? `s3 sync`?

Is there a way to download all the files located under the folder in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket/VER1 [name-of-local-directory]
```

From my experience, it will download in parallel but it won't necessarily use the full bandwidth because there is a lot of overhead for each object. (It is more efficient for large objects, since there is less overhead.)

It is *possible* that `aws s3 sync` might have problems with a large number of files. You'd have to try it to see whether it works.

If you really wanted full performance, you could write your own code that downloads in massive parallel, but the time saving would probably be lost in the time it takes you to write and test such a program.

Another option is to use `aws s3 sync` to download to an Amazon EC2 instance, then **zip the files** and simply download the zip file. That would reduce bandwidth requirements.